# uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Current

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

When running the code below I get the following exception:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Current
```

Controller:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :finishing_step

  def show
    @user = Current.user
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    render_wizard
  end
private
    def finish_wizard_path
      current_user.update_attributes(complete: true)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for Current.user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
<div><%= f.label :first_name, "First Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :middle_name, "Middle Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :middle_name %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :last_name, "Last Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :phone_number, "Phone Number" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :date_of_birth, "Date of Birth" %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, start_year: 1900 %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :address_first_line, "Address (first line)" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_first_line %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :address_second_line, "Address (second line)" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_second_line %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :city, "City" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :city %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :nationality, "Nationality" %><br />
    <%= country_select(:user, :nationality, {selected: "UG"}) %></div>
    <div>
    <%= f.label :avatar %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :terms_of_service, "Agree to Terms of Service" %> <br>
    <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
  </div>
  <div><%= f.submit "Register" %></div>
  <% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that rails cannot find a class `Current` which you use in your `form_for`. It is looking in the namespace of the view which is why you are getting the slightly cryptic error message. If there definitely is a class `Current` then you would be able to access it using `::Current.user` but I suspect it is not present.

Often the current user is accessed by a method `current_user` using devise. It would be worth double-checking how you should be accessing the current user.